# What is the Nominative of 'uniuscuiusque'?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, new-latin, adjective, spinoza

This is taken from Spinoza's Ethics:

notandum est

Iƒ veram **uniuscujusque** rei definitionem nihil involvere neque exprimere præter rei definitæ naturam.

As I can see, it is Adjective in Genitive and should mean unique, only one of the kind etc.

I cannot to find anything in my dictionary except  'unus,a,um' :

Perhaps it comes from unusquisque, if there exists a word like that? Or perhaps certain words, like  'unus'  and  'quis'  here can be casually written together, without breaking any rules ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's *unusquisque*. Both parts *unus* and *quis* are declined, always in the same case.

It is a compound pronoun meaning 'each single one'.